# Can an npm script publish a package to Github using the Github API?

Tags: bash, npm, github-api, npm-scripts

I'm trying to use this script to make a first commit and publish a package to Github publicly.

`{
  "scripts": {
    "first": "git add -A && git commit -m \"First commit\" && A='{\"name\":\"'$npm_package_name'\",\"description\":\"'$npm_package_description'\",\"license_template\":\"'$npm_package_license'\"}' && echo \"${A}\" && curl -u $npm_package_author_name 'https://api.github.com/'$npm_package_author_name'/'$npm_package_name -d \"$A\" && git remote add origin 'https://github.com/'$npm_package_author_name'/'$npm_package_name'.git' && git push -u origin master"
  }
}`

I keep getting this error.  I've scoured the docs and can't figure out why.  Is this not possible?  Please help!

`{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}`

EDIT:
Here's the working script!  I had to make some changes to merge with Github's origin/master original commit that adds the license file.
[github api create repository doc for reference](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create)

`"first": "O='{\"name\":\"'$npm_package_name'\",\"description\":\"'$npm_package_description'\",\"license_template\":\"'$npm_package_license'\"}' && echo \"${O}\" && curl -u $npm_package_author_name https://api.github.com/user/repos -d \"${A}\" && git add -A && git commit -m \"initial\" && git remote add origin 'https://github.com/'$npm_package_author_name'/'$npm_package_name'.git' && git merge origin/master --allow-unrelated-histories -m $npm_package_version && git push --set-upstream origin master && git push && git push --tags"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and remove commands from your script until it is working, in order to determine what part triggers that message.

The `https://api.github.com/'$npm_package_author_name'/'$npm_package_name` URL seems odd, since The [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) usually has a generic name after `https://api.github.com/`, like `https://api.github.com/user` ([User API](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-the-authenticated-user))

You could also consider more established npm packages, like [release-it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/release-it).

Comment: Thanks haha I thought the word user in https://api.github.com/user was just a place holder for the user's name 

Comment: @quinton.ashley Yes, generally the placeholders are `:xxx` (colon first), like `GET /users/:username`: you need to replace `:username`, not `users`.